# for loops in object within object

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why doesn't this work?

I have two objects within an object. I use for loops to print out each property within the nested objects, one after another.

```
var people = {
    john: {
        name: "John",
        age: 20
    },
    bob: {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 40
    }
};

for (var person in people) {
    for (var property in person) { 
        console.log(property);
    }
}
```

I expect it to print out:

```
name
age
name
age
```

Instead I get:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
```

1) What am I doing wrong?

2) What exactly is the console doing to output the numbers above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because in the second (*nested*) `for` loop you iterate *string-valued* `person` variables which hold property names ***(not values!)*** of `people` object. You should change it to `people[person]`:

```
for (var property in people[person]) { 
    console.log(property);
}
```

The numbers above correspond to indices of chars in string values:

```
0: j    0: b
1: o    1: o
2: h    2: b
3: n
```

Comment: Actually, the numbers correspond to the indexes of `john` and `bob`. :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ah yeah! I mixed up everything `:D`

Answer (score 2):

When you do a `for..in`, you are iterating over the keys, not the values.

In `for (var person in people)`, `person` is a string; each of the keys: `"john"`, and `"bob"`.

In your second loop, you are iterating over all the properties of that string, which prints the "indexes" in the string (you can access strings like arrays `string[1]`).

You need to get the object value before you can loop over it:

```
for (var person in people) {
    var thisPerson = people[person];
    for (var property in thisPerson) { 
        console.log(property);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do as vision says above to print out the properties, use the below to get the actual vals

you need to specify the value instead of just the index which is what for in does. you need to do something like

```
for (var person in people) {
    for (var property in people[person]) { 
        console.log(people[person][property]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't print his expected output, it will print the names and ages, not the words "name" and "age".

Comment: yeah i misunderstood the question at first.